# How to check that a variable has new lines characters only

Tags: shell, zsh, string

How do I check the variable `$last_cmd` has new lines only and nothing else in Zsh?

Ideally done via substitution, as this is part of a prompt script, so needs to be really fast.

The following gives me a `bad substitution` error:

```
if [[ -n "${$last_cmd/\n/}" ]]; then
  no_new_lines=1
fi
```

Basically want the equivalent of the following:

```
if [[ -n "$(echo -n $last_cmd)" ]]; then
  no_new_lines=1
fi
```

Comment: Your syntax is broken (it should be `${var/pat/rpl}` not `${$var/pat/rpl}`, you should use `//` instead of `/` to replace all matches, and `\n` will match just `n` not newline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a regex:

```
if [[ $1 =~ ^$'\n'*$ ]]; then
  echo empty or only contains newlines
else
  echo contains non-newline characters 
fi
```

With wildcards, instead of directly testing that there are only newlines, test for the presence of a non-newline character:

```
if [[ $1 == *[^$'\n']* ]]; then
  echo contains non-newline characters 
else
  echo empty or only contains newlines
fi
```

Or the plain sh way:

```
nl='
'
case $1 in
  *[!$nl]*) echo contains non-newline characters;;
  *) echo only contains newlines;;
esac
```

For a positive match with wildcards, you'd need the `#` `extendedglob` operator (the equivalent of the `*` regexp operator):

```
set -o extendedglob
if [[ $1 == $'\n'# ]]; then
  echo empty or only contains newlines
else
  echo contains non-newline characters 
fi
```

Comment: So, an empty string only contains newlines?

Comment: @mosvy Yes, sure.

Comment: h‎o‎w c‎o‎m‎e?‎

Comment: @mosvy Does a sidewalk stop being for pedestrians only when nobody is walking on it?

Comment: That's a way to look at it. So "Jen is only wearing pink underwear" is the same as "Jen is never wearing any underwear". For the sake of clarity, I would avoid playing with vacuous statements.

Comment: @mosvy In mathematical and technical contexts, zero exists. In everyday language, it depends.

Comment: The question is more like: `Are there only pedestrians (no bikes, etc.) on the sidewalk?`, or like: `Is there only water in a glass?`. Not like `Is a glass still a glass when it is empty?` or `Is a sidewalk still a sidewalk when there are cars on it?`.